# How to format identation for stream operators in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, stream

I'd like to auto-format the stream operator in Eclipse in the following way:

```
std::cout << "Creating a cache entry for initial data for staff = "
          << std::endl;

nmspace::myspecialstream << "Some text is printed here."
                         << nmspace::endl;
```

Essentially, I'd like the stream operator to align on the next line with the first stream operator on the previous line. There is a way to do similar formatting for function arguments where function arguments are aligned on each line with the first the argument, consider example:

```
void Manager::func(nmspace::SomeVeryLongType::SomeTypeWithinThatLongType arg1,
                   int arg2);
```

Wondering if that is possible to do it for streams as well?

Comment: Is this more a question about how to set up Eclipse's options?

Comment: Yes, I can't seem to find anything in properties that would do that, maybe because I don't understand all 1000 style properties there are. Maybe there is a way to do style corrections based on style scripts? Or the tool itself could be modified to do what I want...